# How to insert a list inside a list, by this example?

Tags: c, linked-list

I need this code to be a list in the comments that it says to be a list.
I don't know how to make it to be one.

Basically I'm going to have a list "Orcamentos", and one "orcamento" needs to have a list of items, but I'm a little lost...

Would appreciate some help.

```
    struct Utilizador{
    char username[T_LOGIN];
    char password[T_LOGIN];
    char nome[T_STRINGS];
    short int tipo_user; // 1 - Admin / 2 - Decisor
};

    struct Itens{
    char descricao[T_STRINGS];
    int quantidade;
    double preco_uni;
};

    struct Orcamento{
    int numero;
    char identificador[T_STRINGS];
    char nome_fonecedor[T_STRINGS];
    char descricao[T_STRINGS];
    double total;
    struct Itens *itens; // THIS NEEDS TO BE A LIST
    short int estado; // 1 - para analisar / 2 - em análise / 3 - analisado
};

    struct Decisao{
    int desisao; // 0 - não aprovado / 1 - aprovado
    char data[10];
    char justificacao[T_STRINGS];
    struct Utilizador *users; // THIS NEEDS TO BE A LIST
};

    typedef struct Utilizador UTILIZADOR;
    typedef struct Itens ITENS;
    typedef struct Orcamento ORCAMENTO;
    typedef struct Decisao DECISAO;

    typedef UTILIZADOR TIPO_A;
    typedef ITENS TIPO_B;
    typedef ORCAMENTO TIPO_C;
    typedef DECISAO TIPO_D;
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
typedef struct item {
    struct item *anterior;
    TIPO_A dado;
    struct item *seguinte;
} ITEM;

struct lista {
    ITEM *primeiro;
    ITEM *ultimo;
};

typedef struct item2 {
    struct item2 *anterior;
    TIPO_B dado;
    struct item2 *seguinte;
} ITEM2;

struct lista2 {
    ITEM2 *primeiro;
    ITEM2 *ultimo;
};

typedef struct item3 {
    struct item3 *anterior;
    TIPO_C dado;
    struct item3 *seguinte;
} ITEM3;

struct lista3 {
    ITEM3 *primeiro;
    ITEM3 *ultimo;
};

typedef struct item4 {
    struct item4 *anterior;
    TIPO_D dado;
    struct item4 *seguinte;
} ITEM4;

struct lista4 {
    ITEM4 *primeiro;
    ITEM4 *ultimo;
};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
typedef struct lista DLLIST; // Users
typedef struct lista2 DLLIST2; // Itens
typedef struct lista3 DLLIST3; // Orçamentos
typedef struct lista4 DLLIST4; // Decisões
```

Comment: When you say *needs to be a list*, do you mean a *linked list* or an *array* (static or dynamic) or something else?

Comment: I will have a Double Linked List named for "Orcamento", and inside each node of that list i need to have a Double Linked List for "Itens" as part of some field.
What i'm trying to say is, in one node of the list "Orcamento", there is a field that is a Linked List, but i'm having difficulties with that...hope it was easy to understand!

Comment: Do you already have some code for the doubly linked list?

Comment: Yes, i have...i'll try and add it to this question...

Comment: You need to add pointers to the structs Ornament, Utilizador and Itens. These pointers must point to themselves. That way each struct can point to another struct, thus forming a list.

Comment: Please also use English identifiers for easy reading by everyone here (This is an English website).

Comment: Oh, yes! Sorry about that...i'm new here.

Comment: I have it in different files, that's why the separators...

Comment: each member of the *outer* list is simply a pointer to the head of the inner list.

Comment: In the main file, i have DLLIST3 *Orcamentos = NULL; ant that's my outer list, so when it receives it's TIPO_C data, in that data there's a field that needs to be a Linked List of "Items", that's the thing i don't know how to code...

Comment: You would need to replace the `struct Itens *itens;` member in `struct Orcamento` with `DLLIST2 itens;`, for example. You may need to rearrange the source code a bit so that everything is defined in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, i've already thought of that...i'll give it a try...

Comment: Also, do you *really* need so many typedefs? Typedefs are supposed to make the code more readable, but in your case they are making the code less readable.

Comment: I'm not sure that `typedef` double-obscuring the type is a good way to do it; is there any reason why you don't `struct Utilizador{...}; struct Utilizadores { struct Utilizadores *anterior, *seguinte; struct Utilizador dado; };`?

Comment: @hffm - Are you sure that doubly linked lists will serve you better than allocated arrays?

Comment: This is a college project, have to use them mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this, and got it working...

Maybe it's not the most efficient way but...it works for know...

```
struct Utilizador{
    char username[T_LOGIN];
    char password[T_LOGIN];
    char nome[T_STRINGS];
    short int tipo_user; // 1 - Admin / 2 - Decisor
};

typedef struct Utilizador UTILIZADOR;
typedef UTILIZADOR TIPO_A;
typedef struct lista DLLIST; // Users

struct Itens{
    char descricao[T_STRINGS];
    int quantidade;
    double preco_uni;
};

typedef struct Itens ITENS;
typedef ITENS TIPO_B;
typedef struct lista2 DLLIST2; // Itens

struct Orcamento{
    int numero;
    char identificador[T_STRINGS];
    char nome_fonecedor[T_STRINGS];
    char descricao[T_STRINGS];
    double total;
    DLLIST2 *itens;
    short int estado; // 1 - para analisar / 2 - em análise / 3 - analisado
};

typedef struct Orcamento ORCAMENTO;
typedef ORCAMENTO TIPO_C;
typedef struct lista3 DLLIST3; // Orçamentos

struct Decisao{
    int desisao; // 0 - não aprovado / 1 - aprovado
    char data[10];
    char justificacao[T_STRINGS];
    DLLIST *decisores;
};

typedef struct Decisao DECISAO;
typedef DECISAO TIPO_D;
typedef struct lista4 DLLIST4; // Decisões
```